# Bash "time" builtin in string does not execute

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

```
$ cmd='time sleep 2'
$ $cmd
bash: time: command not found
```

What's going on here?  It's not a matter of shell builtins not working, because this works:

```
$ cmd2='echo wef'
$ $cmd2
wef
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I found a difference:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

Vs:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

So the question now is - why does a builtin work in a string and a keyword does not?

Comment: Both commands work as expected for me.  What is the output of `which time`?  You may not have the `time` command installed.

Comment: Wow, you are right, @Steven. I thought it had to be double quotes instead... but it indeed works. Maybe it's a $PATH issue!

Comment: `time` is part of bash, I have no `time` binary installed.

Comment: Shell keywords are not evaluated after expansion. You would need to use /bin/time or use eval around it.

Comment: @eckes You win.  Man what a weird little gotcha.  Write your comment as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow thanks, added,some fluff to the answer so it is worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` as a *GNU Bash* keyword has a very specific location where is is accepted, see for example the syntax for a command pipeline construct:

> The format for a pipeline is
>       `[time [-p]] [!] command1 [| command2 ...]`

This does hardcode the position of the keyword outside the expansions (as *commandN* will be where the parameters and variables are expanded). In fact also the semantic applies to the whole pipeline, not the command, so this is probably why it has to be a keyword.

There is a shell built-in `times` (in POSIX a [special built-in](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/times.html)), for this the expansion works since the first word can be a executable or a shell built-in.

Alternatively *GNU coreutils*  contains a `/bin/time` executable.

In fact `time` is no [reserved word](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_04) in *POSIX Shell* (although bash recognizes it in [posix mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html) anyway (unless a `-` follows for non-obvious reasons)).

Inside an `eval` expression keywords are recognized by *bash*, so this can be used to dynamically enhance commands with time profiling. (However it does on the other hand require an additional round of quoting)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cmd='time sleep 2' try to use it as cmd='/usr/bin/time sleep 2' to get the real time command.

You can read the following in the man time:

Users of the bash shell need to use an explicit path in order to run
  the external time command and not the shell builtin variant.  On system
  where time is installed in /usr/bin, the first example would become
       /usr/bin/time wc /etc/hosts

Comment: Yeah I would have gone this route for my solution but it seems that /usr/bin/time is not installed by default on Debian 8 server systems, so rather than install the dependency it's easier for me to just eval.